# Haskell function parameter force evaluation

Tags: haskell

I need to take last `n` elements from list, using `O(n)` memory so I wrote this code

```
take' :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
take' n xs = (helper $! (length $! xs) - n + 1) xs
    where helper skip [] = []
          helper skip (x : xs) = if skip == 0 then xs else (helper $! skip - 1) xs

main = print (take' 10 [1 .. 100000])
```

this code takes `O(|L|)` memory where `|L|` -- is the length of given list.

But when I write this code

```
take' :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
take' n xs = helper  (100000 - n + 1) xs
    where helper skip [] = []
          helper skip (x : xs) = if skip == 0 then xs else (helper $! skip - 1) xs


main = print (take' 10 [1 .. 100000])
```

This code now takes only `O(n)` memory (the only chage is `(helper $! (length $! xs) - n + 1)` -> `helper  (100000 - n + 1)`)

So, as I understand, Haskell for some reason doesn't evaluate `length xs` before the first call of `helper` so it leaves a thunk in `skip` and haskell has to keep this value in every stack frame instead of making tail recursion. But in second piece of code it evaluates `(100000 - n + 1)` and gives the pure value to the `helper`.

So the problem is how to evaluate the length of list before the first call of helper and use only `O(n)` memory.

Comment: There's a "well-known" trick for doing this, which I wouldn't expect you to guess without a hint. Hint: use a list instead of a number for the `skip` argument.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen seems like the solution is the last answer. thanks anyway for hint =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second version does not really take only *O*(*n*) memory. Regardless of what `take'` does: you start off with a list of length *L*, and that has to be stored somewhere.

The reason it *effectively* takes *O*(*n*) memory is that the list is only used by one “good consumer” here, namely `helper`. Such a consumer deconstructs the list from head to last; because no reference to the head is needed anywhere else, the garbage collector can immediately start cleaning up those first elements – before the list comprehension has even built up the rest of the list!

That changes however if before using `helper` you compute the `length` of that list. This already forces the entire list to be NF'd<sup>†</sup>, and as I said this inevitably takes *O*(*L*) memory. Because you're still holding a reference to be used with `helper`, in this case the garbage collector can *not* take any action before the whole list is in memory.

So, it really has nothing to do with strict evaluation. In fact the only way you could achieve your goal is by making it *less* strict (require only a sublist of length *n* to be evaluated at any given time).

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>More precisely: it forces the list's *spine* to normal form. The elements aren't evaluated, but it's still *O*(*L*).</sub>

Comment: Yeah, when I told about memory I was talking about `bytes maximum residency` field. Thanks a lot for your answer, knowing whats really wrong I can think how to fix it :)

Comment: This meaning of "good consumer" isn't the [one used in the GHC documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html#idp26293440) - that refers to a consumer that can *fuse* at compilation time with a list argument that is itself a "good producer". That's even more efficient than the current case, which is just basic laziness.

Comment: @ Ørjan Johansen right, but isn't lazy deconstruction pretty much the requirement for a good consumer?

Comment: Well maybe. I am worried that even with lazy deconstruction you could have flow control too complicated to be efficiently straightened into a use of `foldr`. Although I don't have an example.

Answer (score 8):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33048102/2541573) referred to what it means to be a good consumer. You have posted two versions of your function, one which works for arbitrary-length lists but is not a good consumer, and one which is a good consumer but assumes a particular list length. For completeness, here is a function that is a good consumer and works for arbitrary list lengths:

```hs
takeLast n xs = go (drop n xs) xs where
    go (_:xs) (_:ys) = go xs ys
    go _ ys = ys
```

Comment: You can avoid the impossible error by removing the first branch and replacing the third with `go _ ys = ys`.

Comment: @dfeuer Nice! Updated.

Comment: oh, very beautiful solution. I didn't think that way)